# SQL Server Data Tools - Recovery Mode

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-data-tools

I am using SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) to manage my database schema.   Every time I choose to publish changes to my schema, the script contains the following bit:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]
           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
    BEGIN
        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
            SET RECOVERY FULL 
            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

    END
```

The problem is, I don't want it to change my recover mode to FULL.   I would like it to be SIMPLE.

How can I modify my SSDT project to indicate that I want simple recovery mode, so that it will stop trying to change it to full every time I publish it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, found this option (and a lot more) within the "database settings" button in the project settings.   A bit hidden IMO :)

[image: SSDT Database Settings]